# Контроль целостности данных в mySQL  MyISAM

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Для хранения данных сайта используются  таблицы MyISAM, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в этом случае производить контроль целостности данных, например, при вставке записи сначала в родительскую, потом в дочернюю таблицу.  Проверками уже в php-коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [похожая тема на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization). В общем суть: либо использовать InnoDB и транзакции, либо лишние запросы и проверки на стороне php.